# How to load datatables correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an issue with datatables, I admit it's my first expirence with that plugin, so maybe something a bit silly.

this is the Object that I'm trying to send :

```
{"FacebookName":{"4":"Eli Shlymovich","5":"Lilach Chen","6":"Ben Berenson"},"FacebookID":{"4":"528537982","5":"530334757","6":"536336508"}}
```

ofcourse it's changes all the time: the error I get is : https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2icq75t0ff85bv/Screenshot%202013-11-22%2020.36.29.png

I have tried to manualy load it with this code:

```
var testdata = [{"id":"58","country_code":"UK","title":"Legal Director","pubdate":"2012-03-08 00:00:00","url":"http://..."}
```

and it worked very good.

so it's kinda of a weird issue, I see that I might have to change something in that object, but I dont succeed to make it work.

This is the Javascript part:

```
   $(document).ready(function()
                 {
                     var  stringifyFB = JSON.stringify(MasterObject);
                     console.log(stringifyFB);
                     $('#test').dataTable({

                         "aaData": stringifyFB,
                         "aoColumns":[{"mData" : "FacebookName"},
                             { "mData" : "FacebookID"}]

                     });
                 });
```

Comment: Seems the testdata is an array, you are sending an object. Change "aaData": stringifyFB" to ""aaData": [stringifyFB]"

Comment: changed it, same error mate.

Answer (score 0):

I looked on examples on [DataTables example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects_subarrays.html)

and I thing it should be working

```
{
    "aaData": [
    {
       "FacebookName": "value",
       "FacebookID": "value"
    },
    {
       "FacebookName": "Trident",
       "FacebookID": "Internet Explorer 5.0"
    }

   ]
}
```

You return object and in property: "aaData" you have array of objects and values corresponding to the keys.

Comment: I dont see how it can help me on that case, I know that if I set a regualr array, it works.
it's a problem when I send that MasterObject or stringifyFB as I present on question.
The solution I need is for that type of object, Cant seem to find one yet.